# I want to get a text from a page which is changed after login selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

I want to get a text from a page which will be opened after I login, but I don't have an idea how to do so, currently the URL is `https://www.tdscpc.gov.in/app/login.xhtml` after login, it opens a page `https://www.tdscpc.gov.in/app/` so I want to get a Text from the second page,
thanks

```
 static WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        String exePath = "C:\\Users\\Dell\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exePath);
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://www.tdscpc.gov.in/app/login.xhtml");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/input"))
                .click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/p[2]/input"))
                .sendKeys("*******");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[6]/p[2]/input"))
                .sendKeys("*******");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[8]/p[4]/input[3]")).
                sendKeys("*******");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        while (driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[12]/p[2]/input")).o) {

//This is the value which is on the new page, i want to get this value from the page, the page opens automatically once login is done, i just want to get this element froom a page which opens after login (Like the Dashboard) 
            String name = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/text()")).getText();
            String nameInReplace = name.replace("Welcome ", "");
            System.out.println(nameInReplace);
        }
    }
```

Edit2-
I Think that the Driver is getting the Element from the first URL, which is invalid as the element is not present there, how do i change it so it detects it from the new page and not the first page?

Comment: just login and get the text , hwat error you get if you try that

Comment: @PDHide i tried a #wait(); but it didnt work as thought

Comment: @vN1t What error do you see?

Comment: @DebanjanB Element not found

Comment: @DebanjanB thanks a lot sir, for replying, you are doing a great job, selenium is the best tool for web automation right now, it has saved me a ton of money, i can now code my api for my self rather than buying it for high price

Answer (score 0):

maybe u can use

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("...")));
```

it waits until the element you want to reach appears

Comment: does that work if the element will load after the new page loads?

Comment: i tried it and i got this error
a.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)

What data type should i use for the text, String doesnt work